# Carla does not launch (Ubuntu Studio 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-studio

Carla will not launch on my system at all. Or rather, it looks like it launches for a fraction of a second then immediately crashes again. No error messages. Any ideas?

Comment: Clear the cache

Comment: I cleared the system cache: I assume that was what was meant. Stil same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer from the developer:

The Ubuntu Studio Backports PPA contains newer versions of select software that is included with Ubuntu Studio. For more info, such as how to add this PPA to your system, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA

After enabling the backports ppa Carla updated to 2.5.4 – works.